# argparse - Optional argument with list/tuple

Tags: python, argparse

I have several optional arguments and one of them needs to store multiple values - i.e. its type is neither string nor integer. Does argparse support optional arguments of other types?

For example, I would like this command:

```
>>> python example1 test_project --name try1 3
```

to be the equivalent of code like this:

```
args.name = {'try1', '3'}
```

Is this possible? Or will I be forced to use `action='store_true'` and then prompt the user for more information if he choose this option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm really having a hard time following your question.  Is this what you want?

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--name',nargs='*',action='store')

print(parser.parse_args('--name try1 3'.split())) #Namespace(name=['try1', '3'])
```

If it isn't, perhaps you could try to be a little more clear with what you want to make argparse do, and what you've been able to do with it.

Comment: @mgilson @Gil.I Gil, based on the title, your acceptance of this answer, and you using `nargs *` I am guessing that what you wanted to do was collect multiple arguments from the command line and store all of them inside `name`? I am also guessing that you typing `-name` with one `-` was a typo in the original question? Based on these guesses I have heavily copyedited the original question to try and make it more clear. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @mgilson I have updated the answer now that the question is clear. Hope that's okay.